# Save whole table html code in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table where the cell content is editable. 
Now I want, after I finished editing the table, the html code from the table with all values.

Here is a table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered content">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>bla</th>
            <th>bla bla</th>
            <th>bla bla bla </th>
            <th>more bla</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr contenteditable="true">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr contenteditable="true">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<button id="save">Save</button>
```

That's my JS code:

```
    $('#save').on('click', function () {
        var table = $('.content').html();
        alert(table);
    });
```

The problem is that if I console.log the table variable I get this output:

```
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>bla</th>
            <th>bla bla</th>
            <th>bla bla bla </th>
            <th>more bla</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr contenteditable="true">
            <td>dwad</td>
            <td>dwada</td>
            <td>dawdaw</td>
            <td>dawdaw</td>
        </tr>
        <tr contenteditable="true">
            <td>daw<br></td>
            <td>daw<br></td>
            <td>dwadaw<br></td>
            <td>daw<br></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

If you have a closer look you can see that the

`<table class=" ... ">` and the `</table>` tag are gone but I also need them. 
Does someone know what I can do to also get the table-tags ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`outerHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) on the node element. Like this:

```
$('#save').on('click', function () {
    var table = $('.content')[0].outerHTML;
    alert(table);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var table = $('.content')[0].outerHTML;
alert(table);
```

Should work in every browser

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`Element.outerHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

> The `outerHTML` attribute of the element `DOM` interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants. It can be set to replace the element with nodes parsed from the given string.

```
$('#save').on('click', function () {
    var table = $('.content');
    alert(table.get(0).outerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use outerHTML

```
$('.content').get(0).outerHTML
```

[Check the example on JSfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4f4sx6t/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#save').on('click', function () {
        var table = $('.content')[0].html();
        alert(table);
 });
```

This should work.